# Reduce execution time of query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

I want to reduce the time taken by the query in mysql.

There are three tables say

1. A ~600k rows,
2. B ~2K rows,
3. C ~100K rows

having 2 columns each.

1. A has one column which is used in aggregation and other to join with table B.
2. B has one column to join with A and other with C
3. C has one column to join with B and other column to group by.

What should be the indexing plan to reduce the run time.  As of now it is using temporary tables and then file sort. Is there any way we could avoid temporary tables.

Sample query :

```
 SELECT
      sum(`revenue_facts`.`total_price`) AS `m0`
FROM 
    `category_groups` AS `category_groups`,
    `revenue_facts` AS `revenue_facts`,
    `dim_products` AS `dim_products`
WHERE 
    `dim_products`.`product_category_group_sk` =       `category_groups`.`product_category_group_sk` AND  
    `revenue_facts`.`product_sk` = `dim_products`.`product_sk`
GROUP BY `category_groups`.`category_name`;
```

I already have indexes on group by column and the columns in join.

my query is currently taking **6 minute**s. I want to reduce the time taken. table structure is as

table A :

```
CREATE TABLE `revenue_facts` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_sk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_sk` (`product_sk`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table B :

```
CREATE TABLE `dim_products` (
  `product_sk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_category_group_sk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_sk`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
 KEY (`product_sk`) (`product_sk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table C :

```
CREATE TABLE `category_groups` (
  `product_category_group_sk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_sk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_category_group_sk`,`category_sk`),
  KEY `category_sk` (`category_sk`),
  KEY `product_category_group_sk` (`product_category_group_sk`
  KEY `category_sk` (`category_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Execution plan used is:

```
1   SIMPLE  dim_products    index   PRIMARY,product_category_group_index    product_category_group_index    8   NULL    651264  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  category_groups ref PRIMARY,category_sk,product_category_group_sk,category_name product_category_group_sk   8 etl_testing.dim_products.product_category_group_sk    4   Using index
1   SIMPLE  revenue_facts   ref product_sk  product_sk  8 etl_testing..dim_products.product_sk  5   NULL
```

Comment: Post your table structures and explain plan

Comment: Your indexes seem to be fine.. What is your problem? How slow is your query exactly?

Comment: There is no way to escape temporary and filesort if you are using a join and group by like this. Add more information on what exactly are you trying to do. Using  FROM table_name AS table_name just makes the query ugly. And it would be helpfull if you actually say what table is A,B,C so we don't have to look in that long where to deduct who is who.

Comment: Added table structure and the execution plan used. query is taking more than 6 minutes .

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    sum(`revenue_facts`.`total_price`) AS `m0`
FROM 
    (`dim_products` LEFT JOIN `category_groups` ON `dim_products`.`product_category_group_sk` =  `category_groups`.`product_category_group_sk`)
    LEFT JOIN `revenue_facts` ON `dim_products`.`product_sk` = `revenue_facts`.`product_sk`
GROUP BY `category_groups`.`category_name`;
```

Also, as Abdul said:

"Post your table structures and explain plan"

Comment: should be INNER join.

Comment: Is using the join keyword faster than usinh where conditions?